# Is there any equavalent of sg3_utils for windows

Tags: windows, scsi

Is there an equivalent of sg3_utils for windows? I need to query the Page 83 information of a physical disk and read it's LUN name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

download sg_utils for windows from 
http://sg.danny.cz/sg/p/sg3_utils-1.37exe.zip

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. It's better to go here:  http://sg.danny.cz/sg/p/ then search for the file named sg3_utils-x.xxexe.zip with the highest number or most recent date. I just installed sg3_utils-1.42exe and it works on Win Server 2022.

The first question I had was how do you address the disk or storage device you wish to access with sg_utils. After some digging I found that you use the \.\PHYSICALDRIVEx path. E.g.

```
sg_raw -r 1k \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 12 00 00 00 60 00
```

A good way to ID or map your PHYSICALDRIVE numbers is to use the command:

```
wmic diskdrive list brief /format:list
```